# get the column of a cell in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For each row in my dataframe, I have identified the maximum value. I would like to get the column in which each maximum is in. For example,

```
myDict = {}
for i in df.index:
    maximum = max(df.iloc[i])
    myDict{i} = (columnOfMaximum, maximum)
```

What is the correct selection routine to get `columnOfMaximum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df[['a', 'b', 'c']].idxmax(axis=1)` will give you the names of the columns with maximum values (e.g. if you have 4 rows it will give you `[a,c,b,c]`)

```
myDict = {}

for i,cm,mx in zip(df.index, df.idxmax(axis=1), df.max(axis=1)):
    myDict[i] = cm,mx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use iterators

```
it = iter(zip(df.idxmax(axis=1).values, df.max(axis=1).values))
myDict = dict(zip(list(range(df.shape[0])), it))
```